# Python MySQL - MySQLdb - apostrophe in string breaks entry

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

Hi am inserting strings into a MySQL database which is working fine, up until one of my strings contains an apostrophe, as which point it breaks, and doesn't enter anything into the database. It is the title string which may contain odd characters, apostrophe, speech marks, etc. I have tried MySQLdb.escape_string(title) but still can't get it to work, maybe I was using it wrongly.

```
insert = "insert into %s (location, mode, process, status, title) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (self.params["tableName"], location, transporterMode, "-", "Queued", MySQLdb.escape_string(self.title))
cur.execute(insert)
self.params["db"].commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly why you should not use string interpolation. The DB API has a well-documented way of providing string parameters, which apart from solving your problem with apostrophes, will also protect you from SQL injection.

```
insert = "insert into {} (location, mode, process, status, title) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)".format(self.params['tableName'])
cur.execute(insert, (location, transporterMode, "-", "Queued", self.title))
```

Note that you do not quote the placeholders yourself, and you pass the set of params as the second argument to cursor.execute. Also note you *do* need to use string interpolation for the table name: I've used the newer `format` syntax so that it does not try to replace the other placeholders.

Comment: Works great, thanks, you missed a closing bracket on the last line. Thanks again.

Comment: All good, but currently when I get the values back from the database I still have the backslash escape character in the string.

Comment: You mustn't escape your input variables. Just use them.

Comment: I am using them on input, but don't want a backslash in my string when reading back.

Comment: Thanks, added the missing paren. I'm not sure what you mean about the backslashes though: sounds like that's just the `repr` in the Python shell. If you do `print whatever` does that look OK? If not you probably should ask a new question.